# Difference between *device descriptor* and *device handler*

Tags: operating-systems

I am studying Computer Architecture,
and am a bit confused about the difference between device descriptors and device handlers in operating systems. Am I correct in saying that a device handler is actually a device driver?

What confuse me is that while the terms 
*device handler* and *device handler* appear in the course slides,
I couldn't find then in the course textbook.
The closest term I could find there is *device driver*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you find that terminology? Check how it is defined there.

If it was up to me, a "device descriptor" would be a way to describe a device, perhaps a data structure giving details on it (or some sort of reference to it, like a pointer or an index into an array of the above).

As you state, in my book a "device handler" would be some sort of routine (or a set of routines) to manage it, a driver.

Comment: thanks vonbrand, I was looking for  confirmation.